# HTML Canvas: Why Is my image on the canvas so blurry?

Tags: image, html5-canvas

I am making a grid for a pathfinding visualizer, and I am concerned that my image icon is very low resolution in the grid cell. I am not sure if this is supposed to be like this due to the small size of the image, but I thought I would ask why it is so blurry and if there is a way to fix it?

[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CaxzC.png)

[Image on canvas grid(low res)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81V2v.png)

This is my css for the canvas:

```
#myCanvas{

    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #000000;

    position: absolute;
    top: 60%;
    transform: translate(0, -50%);  
    left: 0;
    right: 0;

    width : pixelWidth * devicePixelRatio;
    height: pixelHeight * devicePixelRatio;

    transform: translate(0.5, 0.5);
}
```

This is the canvas in the html:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1235" height="520">
</canvas>
```

Comment: I would suggest you to use a `.png` image.I think the white background in your image is also taking space inside the grid and causing a low resolution.

Comment: We need to see how you do draw this image, how you do declare your canvas, how you do style it, etc. i.e a [mcve]

Comment: Kaiido: See my edit:

Comment: I tried using a transparent png and I still got the same problem

Answer (score 2):

Default context width and height are 300 and 150 respectively. This means that your canvas (no matter how large) is a 300 * 150 image, which blurs your smaller image a lot.

Try:

```
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.canvas.height = innerHeight; //or your desired height 
context.canvas.width = innerWidth;// or your desired width
context.canvas.style.imageRendering = 'auto';//default
```